# Check if each element of my list param contains all data string passed as a parameter

Tags: java, performance

My code below is working but I am searching for performance and improvement. 
It consists of looping my `PartList`  elements and check if my string parameter `orginalDataStringList` contains the elements on label string for each `Part` element.

```
private boolean excludeAllInformationVariation(List<String> orginalDataStringList, PartList parts) {
    for (Part part : parts) {
        List<String> listTemp = new ArrayList<String>();
        listTemp.addAll(orginalDataStringList);
        if (!part.getOptLogic().isLabelNullOrEmpty()) {
            String[] dataArrays = part.getOptLogic().getLabel().split("( )");
            for (String data : dataArrays) {
                listTemp.remove(data);
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        if (!listTemp.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

```
public class PartList extends ArrayList<Part> {
    public PartList() {
        //Empty constructor
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Part {
    private Logic optLogic;
    public Logic getOptLogic() { return optLogic; }
    public void setOptLogic(Logic optLogic) { this.optLogic = optLogic; }
}
```

---

```
public class Logic {
    private String label;
    public String getLabel() { return label; }
    public void setLabel(String label) { this.label = label; }
}
public boolean isLabelNullOrEmpty() {
    return (this.getLabel() == null || this.getLabel().isEmpty()) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: `return (condition) ? true : false;` don't do that! Just return the condition!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing your code.

## Naming

Finding good names is the most important but also hardest part in programming. So always take your time to find good names that express your intention of what the code does.

The name of your method `excludeAllInformationVariation` is a lie. It implies that there is something changed either in the object itself (its state) or the passed parameter object. But this method does not alters neither the objects stat nor the parameter.
Therefore it should have a different name. 
Since it returns a boolean this name should start with `is` or `has`.
eg.: `isAllDataCovered(...)`

## Single Responsibility / Separation of Concerns

Your  classes `Part` and `Logic` look like  *data transfer objects* (DTOs), but the method `isLabelNullOrEmpty()` is some kind of business logic.

You should not mix DTOs with business logic. The method `isLabelNullOrEmpty()` should be in the same class as the method  `excludeAllInformationVariation` and have a parameter of type `String` on which it should work.